# javascript replace dash char using regex or otherwise

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this:

```
11111-22222-333---444---55--5566--6-----7-
```

I am using this code:

```
overlaps.replace(/-{2}/g, '-');
```

however it does not work, want i am looking for is that multiple instances of `-` should be replaced with one `-` and ending dash should be removed if any.

Can anybody tell what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: overlaps.replace(/--+/g, '-').replace(/-+$/g, '-');

Comment: To explain why your version does not work : replace will scan the string from left to right replacing each occurrence of matching strings. The scan will continue from immediately beyond the replaced string. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use two regular expressions. This should work fine.

```
overlaps.replace(/-+$|(-)+/g, '$1')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wJLTB/3/

Comment: +1 I love it. This is way better than my multiple replace calls. My regex has gotten rusty due to infrequent use.

Comment: @kalisjoshua sometimes multiple simple regex will perform better than a single complex one... it's worth testing for performance-critical things.

Comment: @GGG I was thinking about the same (about last comment). However, possibly `replace` callback might be even faster. Really worth testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
overlaps.replace(/-+/g, "-").replace(/-$/, "");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wJLTB/1/

Another way is to use callback function:

```
overlaps.replace(/-+/g, function(str, p1, offset) {
    return offset.lastIndexOf("-") == p1 ? "" : "-";
})
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wJLTB/2/

Answer (score 1):

Close but forgot the final condition:

> and ending dash should be removed if any.

So use this instead:

```
overlaps.replace(/-+/g, "-").replace(/-+$/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks cleaner to me:

```
overlaps.replace(/-(?=-|$)/g, '')
```

The expr reads: remove dash followed by another dash or by the end of input.

Comment: The lookahead is almost guaranteed to be slower, though. Looks like it's jsperf time. (edit: looks like it's not jsperf time, jsperf is down right now. Maybe it will be jsperf time later).